# How can I correctly get these ids from my database ? (php/mysql)

Tags: php

I am making a website where users can leave comments about movies. On the moviepage, I want to display these comments.
In my database, I have a table named "critique" which has his own id, the comment of the user, the film's ID it is referring to... 
Right now, I am trying to store in an array all the ids of "critique" that matches with the movie page, and I'm trying to loop through this array. Here's the PHP code :

```
        $ids = $bd->prepare("SELECT id FROM critique WHERE filmID = ?");
        $ids->execute(array($id));
        $listeIDs = $ids->fetch();
        $taille = sizeof($listeIDs);
```

The $id variable is set beforehand in the code. The $taille variable has a value of 2, which corresponds to the number of "critique" existing in my database right now. But I cannot manage to get them.
When trying to echo $listeIDs[0], I get the right value ID for the first entry, but any other value of index will get me an error "Undefined offset", as if the array only contained one value.
How can I retrieve these values ? I'm guessing the issue is with the fetch() command, what else should I use instead ?

Thanks

Comment: You should open a manual. Answer is __already there__

Comment: @Datky What returns `fetch()` ? Answer may be there :)

Answer (score 0):

@Cid Okay I searched a bit more and it's working now, I replaced the fetch() with `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)`

Thanks for the clue